# How to plot from pandas dataframe according to rows so each column is a point

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot a line graph that is going to be fluctuating according to the column values.

My pandas dataframe has 10 columns which represent each day (names of my columns are day1, day2, ..., day10) and 3 rows which each one shows one single feature that I want to look at their changes daily(percentage of daily sales of potato, onion and strawberry).

I have already tried to plot it with

```py
timeseries.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

what I get is :
http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=19_problem.png

("Feature" in this pic is the index's column name and instead of 0,1,2 as row names I have Potato, Onion and Strawbery)

What I want to achieve for each row separately is: http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=19_question.png

I would be so happy if someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to transpose your dataframe:

```
timeseries.T.plot()
```

---

mcve:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 10)), columns=[f'day{i}' for i in range(10)], index=['Potato', 'Onion', 'Strawbery'])

               day0      day1      day2  ...      day7      day8      day9
Potato     0.232951  0.764059  0.876049  ...  0.631673  0.185351  0.139135
Onion      0.516356  0.149735  0.630793  ...  0.389646  0.111144  0.799737
Strawbery  0.768387  0.597404  0.335025  ...  0.950945  0.038993  0.996456

[3 rows x 10 columns]


df.T.plot()
```

[image]

if you wonder why, have a look at `df.T`:

```
df.T
        Potato     Onion  Strawbery
day0  0.232951  0.516356   0.768387
day1  0.764059  0.149735   0.597404
day2  0.876049  0.630793   0.335025
day3  0.442927  0.646496   0.034924
day4  0.794574  0.061397   0.385407
day5  0.517380  0.480174   0.979457
day6  0.068231  0.332127   0.272894
day7  0.631673  0.389646   0.950945
day8  0.185351  0.111144   0.038993
day9  0.139135  0.799737   0.996456
```